# What is the part of speech of "both" in "We ate both sandwiches"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the following sentence, I think *both* is a pronoun, serving as an appositive to *we*.

> We ate both sandwiches.

What is the part of speech of *both* in that sentence?

Comment: You're maybe confusing "We both ate sandwiches" (emphasising that it was 2 of you, not just one, who ate), with "we ate both sandwiches" (emphasising that 2 sandwiches were eaten, which was all there was).

Comment: In your example sentence "both" modifies "sandwiches". It means "the two sandwiches". Is this what you meant to say?  Or did you mean to say "We both ate sandwiches"?  This would mean "The two of us ate sandwiches".

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks, I may confuse it with "we both...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually dependent on "sandwiches", which it modifies. And it's a numeral.

How many sandwiches did we eat? Both sandwiches.

Comment: Isn't 'both' in 'both sandwiches', 'both dogs', 'both cars', etc, a determiner?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Apparently it is (and so I've learned the term) but IIUIR determiners are not a part of speech as such. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner) says: "Common kinds of determiners include definite and indefinite articles (the, a), demonstratives (this, that), possessive determiners (my, their), cardinal numerals (one, two), quantifiers (many, both), distributive determiners (each, every), and interrogative determiners (which, what)." So, they can be articles, several types of pronouns, or numerals.

Comment: A numeral is a symbol or name that stands for a number. Examples: three, four and twelve. Both is a quantifier.

Comment: "Both" expresses quantification but it is not a numeral. Its word class (POS) is determin**ative** and its function is that of determ**iner**, not modifier. Note the different spellings of the two labels.